# Grails, Inserting lots of data using withTransaction results in OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, grails, transactions

I'm using Grails 1.1 beta2. I need to import a large amount of data into my Grails application. If I repeatedly instantiate a grails domain class and then save it, the performance is unacceptably slow. Take for example importing people from a phone book:

```
for (each person in legacy phone book) {
    // Construct new Grails domain class from legacy phone book person
    Person person = new Person(...)
    person.save()
}
```

This turns out be painfully slow. Someone on the Grails mailing list suggest batching up saves in a transaction. So now I have:

```
List batch = new ArrayList()
for (each person in legacy phone book) {
    // Construct new Grails domain class from legacy phone book person
    Person person = new Person(...)
    batch.add(person)
    if (batch.size() > 500) {
        Person.withTransaction {
            for (Person p: batch)
                p.save()
            batch.clear()
        }
    }
}
// Save any remaining
for (Person p: batch)
    p.save()
```

This works must faster, at least initially. Each transaction saves 500 records. As time goes on, the transactions take longer and longer. The first few transactions takes about 5 seconds, then it just creeps from there. After about 100 transactions, each one takes over a minute, which is once again unacceptable. Worse is that eventually Grails will eventually run out of Java heap memory. I can increase the JVM heap size, but that just delays the `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

Any ideas why this is? It's like there some internal resource not being released. The performance gets worse, memory is being held on to, and then eventually the system runs out of memory.

According to the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html), `withTransaction` passes the closure to Spring's `TransactionStatus` object. I couldn't find anything in `TransactionStatus` to close/end the transaction.

**Edit:** I'm running this from Grails' Console (`grails console`)

**Edit:** Here's the out of memory exception:

```
Exception thrown: Java heap space

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hibernate.util.IdentityMap.entryArray(IdentityMap.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.util.IdentityMap.concurrentEntries(IdentityMap.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:655)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:732)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:701)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
```

Comment: Whats the context in which this is executing? A quartz job? A controller? When we've done this in the past using a controller has allowed us to set a loop which can bound the batching size, with the size of subsequent transaction in the Service correspondingly bounded

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a common issue with all hibernate applications and it is caused by the growth of the hibernate session. I'm guessing that the grails console holds a hibernate session open for you in a similar way to the 'open session in view' pattern that I know it uses in for normal web requests.

The solution is to get hold of the current session and clear it after each batch. I'm not sure how you get hold of spring bean using the console, normally for controllers or services you just declare them as members. Then you can get the current session with `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. In order to clear it just call `session.clear()`, or if you what to be selective use `session.evict(Object)` for each `Person` object.

for a controller/service:

```
class FooController {
    def sessionFactory

    def doStuff = {
        List batch = new ArrayList()
        for (each person in legacy phone book) {
            // Construct new Grails domain class from legacy phone book person
            Person person = new Person(...)
            batch.add(person)
            if (batch.size() > 500) {
                Person.withTransaction {
                    for (Person p: batch)
                        p.save()
                    batch.clear()
                }
                // clear session here.
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();
            }
        }
        // Save any remaining
        for (Person p: batch)
            p.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd improve that code using session.clear() each N-th iteration of the loop, not each one.

Comment: completely agree... looking at that code now I'm not sure if it even works.

Answer (score 15):

Ted Naleid wrote a [great blog entry](http://www.naleid.com/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql.html)
 about improving batch performance. Including here as a reference.