# How to get the session or web application context when running via run-script?

Tags: grails

I have a groovy script that's run using Grails's `run-script`. It populates the database from a large amount of static data. Because of [this Grails/Hibernate session issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/431828/24396), I have to clear the session occasionally. If I don't then the app runs out of memory. Thus when running using `run-script`, how do I get a reference to the session or web application context (`GrailsWebApplicationContext`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look inside `_RunScript.groovy` you'll see that the application context and the GrailsApplication object are injected into the binding of your script.

```
def shell = new GroovyShell(classLoader, new Binding(ctx: appCtx, grailsApplication: grailsApp))
```

Once you have those, getting access to the current session is easy, in your script just ask the session factory for the current session, and you can clear it:

```
def currentSession = ctx.sessionFactory.currentSession
currentSession.clear()
```

Comment: Great explanation as to how `ctx` gets injected.

Comment: The answer here is for Groovy scripts run in Grails app contexts with the run-scripts command.  Some sites refer to using `includeTargets << grailsScript("...")`, but that's not necessary for run-scripts, as mentioned in the answer.  What might throw you off is if you attempt to access the `ctx` when defining a `@Field` in your script.  At the time that the `@Field` declaration is evaluated, the `ctx` binding has not yet occurred.  Defer assignments in `@Fields` that refer to `ctx` by just defining them on another line, and it will work.